# How to sort a file containing two sets into two alphabetically ordered sets in Linux shell?

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, text, gnu-sort

I have 2 similar sets of data in a single text file and I want to alphabetically sort the content of these sets independent of each other. The following text block is a part of the text file which is in the format of `name : value`

```
set1 :
scripts : 1168
virt : 541
firmware : 15
init : 315
security : 1529

set2 :    
scripts : 873
init : 84
virt : 402
security : 1720
firmware : 6
```

and I want the output to be sorted as follow:

```
set1 :
firmware : 15
init : 315
scripts : 1168
security : 1529
virt : 541

set2 :    
firmware : 6
init : 84
scripts : 873
security : 1720
virt : 402
```

After a quick research about this problem, I found the following solutions:

1. Split the file into 2 halves and then try to sort them independently
   which is not preferred here because I need to collect these results
   from more than 1000 files.
2. Use Linux `GNU sort` command which has a bit of problem. It sorts the two sets alphabetically but then it orders the same `names` based on their `values`. This means, using `GNU sort`, I am losing the set membership for some rows.

The result for `GNU sort` is which is sorted but it's not correct in the context of this question.

```
firmware : 15
firmware : 6
init : 315
init : 84
scripts : 1168
scripts : 873
security : 1529
security : 1720
set1 :
set2 :
virt : 402
virt : 541
```

Comment: When you say "sort" what do you mean ? what is the expected output of such a file ?

Comment: Update your exact required output for your sample input given.

Comment: @ alfasin, I meant the Linux `sort` command! In a file or else I can redirect the output into a file!

Comment: @ Inian, I've added the required output to the question!

Comment: do you really need to order the data before importing it to your final tool? If loading to a DB, you should add a column for `set num` . Same really for a spreadsheet. OR better still go back to source and create separate files so you can use `sort`. then you can cat f1 f2 f3 f4 .... > combined.txt` . Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, I have already created these text outputs. I know the formatting is not good enough, but reproducing the results with a different format is out of my options right now. I keep your suggestion in mind for my future codes!

Comment: @Inian, I've added the `GNU sort` to the text and also added a new tag `gnu-sort`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BEGIN {
RS="set"
FS="\n"
}

{
# Skip empty sets
if ($0 == "") next

setname = "set"$1
print setname

i = 0
# Start at field 2 to skip first field which is part of "set" name
for (x=2; x<NF; x++) {
    # Ignore blank lines in set
    if ($x != "") {
        data[i] = $x
        i = i + 1
    }
}
n = asort(data)  # NOTE: asort indexes from 1
for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
    print data[i]
}
delete data
}
```

Run the above based on OP input:

awk -f sort.awk input.txt

```
set1 :
firmware : 15
init : 315
scripts : 1168
security : 1529
virt : 541
set2 :
firmware : 6
init : 84
scripts : 873
security : 1720
virt : 402
```